# PHP/PDO - Fetching data from two tables in loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have below PDO prepared statement, where I select data from two tables AND from two different databases.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT 
                t1.id, t1.title, t1.text, t1.time, t1.userid, t1.type, 
                t2.id, t2.text, t2.time, t2.timeline_id, t2.type, t2.url
                        FROM database1.growl t1
                INNER JOIN database2.notifications t2 on t1.userid = t2.timeline_id
                        WHERE t1.userid = :userid AND t2.timeline_id = :userid 
                        ORDER BY t1.time DESC, t2.time DESC"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userdata["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, when I try to access the data from **both** tables, with below code:

```
while($data=$stmt->fetch()){    
    echo $data["text"]; 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

All it is printing out, is the data from the **second database** `database2.notifications`.

My goal is to get data from both tables, and sort the data according the unixtimestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `SELECT`:

```
t1.id, t1.title, t1.text, t1.time, t1.userid, t1.type, 
t2.id, t2.text, t2.time, t2.timeline_id, t2.type, t2.url
```

The column names are identical. Since the table name is not part of the identifier when the data is returned to PHP, the second table data overwrites the first table data. You need to explicitly name your columns like this whenever there are conflicting names:

```
t1.id AS id1, t1.title AS title2, ...
t2.id AS id2, t2.text AS text2, ...
```

Then you would be able to access all of the data in PHP:

```
while($data=$stmt->fetch()){    
    echo $data["text1"]; 
    echo $data["text2"]; 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

---

After clarification, this seems to be what you're looking for:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT title, text, time, type, url
    FROM
    (
        SELECT title, text, time, type, NULL AS url
        FROM database1.growl
        WHERE userid = :uid1
        UNION
        SELECT title, text, time, type, url
        FROM database2.notifications
        WHERE timeline_id = :uid2
    ) subq
    ORDER BY time DESC
SQL;

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':uid1', $userdata["id"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':uid2', $userdata["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! I can get data from both tables now. Although, in my first table there is only 2 rows and in my second there is 10. When I use the above PHP code, the data from my first table is echoed 10 times... How can I prevent that? I just want to show the data from the two tables

Comment: When doing a join, things often get repeated. If you don't want that, you can either keep track of what was echoed (and not echo it again) or execute two separate queries.

Comment: How can I execute two seperate queries and still sort the data by time)

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your query. What you're querying is not a one-to-many relationship but the same type of data from two similar tables, right? You can do a `UNION` of the two individual queries instead of a `JOIN` and still sort the data by time. Eg: `SELECT a, b FROM (SELECT a, b, date FROM t1 UNION SELECT c AS a, d AS b, date FROM t2) subq ORDER BY date` Unless of course this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Well I just want to show the data from the two tables in one page, with one query. The data will be shown in a table, therefore I would like to order by time, no matter what table the data is from.
About the UNION function - would you mind updating your answer with that? I can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: Updated. Let me know if that is what you wanted. You can verify output in PHPMyAdmin/MySQL Workbench first before messing with PHP.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you SO much. Just one question - what is SQL; in the end of the query good for? PhpMyAdmin gives me an error if that is present.

Comment: It's the [heredoc syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Basically I have to repeat the same characters that I put after the `<<<` to end the string. Doesn't have to be `SQL`, it could be anything you want.